# How can I always expand abbrevs with prefixes?

Tags: abbrev

How can I remove the need to use  `M-'` for abbrevs with a prefix?

From the manual:

> You may wish to expand an abbrev and attach a prefix to the expansion; for example, if `cnst` expands into `construction`, you might want to use it to enter `reconstruction`. It does not work to type `recnst`, because that is not necessarily a defined abbrev.  What you can do is use the command `M-'` (`abbrev-prefix-mark`) in between the prefix `re` and the abbrev `cnst`.

I would like to make `cnst` followed by a space always expand into ‘construction’, i.e. without typing `M-'` for `recnst`.